# Atom no detecta los fallos de sintaxis

Tags: c, atom-editor

Recien he instalado el entorno de Atom para programar en C y C++. En este codigo, escrito en C, el compilador no me ha avisado de que había escrito `%s` en lugar de `%d` , por lo que me fallaba pero no sabia por que.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int valor;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
      printf("Valor %d: ", i);
      scanf("%s", &valor); //Aqui debería ser %d
      printf("%d\n", valor);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Instalé el paquete de `gpp-compiler` y `minGW`. ¿Que debo instalar para que me avise de este tipo de cosas?

Comment: Hola, sonlas10. No te aparece ni siquiera un warning parecido a este? `warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’`

Comment: que va @AdrianFusco. Voy a adjuntar una foto con la captura de pantalla para que se entineda mejor

Comment: ¿Has intentado probar con linter-gcc?

Comment: No es un fallo de sintaxis, la función `printf` requiere un argumento de tipo `char *` (además de otros opcionales), y la cadena `"%s"` es una cadena de texto, o `char *`.

Comment: Si compilas con la opción `-Wall` (claro, si usas gcc) todas las advertencias estarán activadas..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracia a la recomendacion de un usuario, he instalado `linter-gcc` y ahora si se recibe el Warning[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]